# Resources (images, custom font, etc.) not showing in app after uploading to AppStore - Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store

I have an app produced in Xamarin Forms and already published on the iOS AppStore. I recently updated the app and when I published it, it was uploaded to the AppStore with no images, tab bar icons, custom font that I had been using, etc. I have been investigating this for a couple of days but cannot come to a conclusion as to why this is happening. When debugging, everything shows as expected. I've even published an Ad-Hoc version of the build and everything is showing as expected with the Ad-Hoc version too.

There are also no issues with the android version on Google Play, so this seems to be happening specifically with the iOS version when being released/distributed to the AppStore.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, do you use local files from resources folder to show, or use online files with url?

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT I am using local files from resources folder to show. I had updated visual studio to the most recent version the day before I published to the app store, could a setting accidentally got changed during the update process? I'm not sure what else could have caused this.

Comment: When you have updated the version of visual studio, do you build it with Ad-Hoc version to check whether it works?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT yes, and it worked just fine with Ad-Hoc version. I ended up having to create a new project and copy the code. Resubmitted to the app store and that took care of the issue.

Comment: Hi, have you checked the [Linking Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows#linker-behavior) and set **Don't Link** to test when select Apple Store versrion?